# Using a method in an if statement

Tags: c#

I'm a complete noob at programming and I was wondering where i went wrong with this simple calculator i was trying. I can't seem to get the program to run the method. I think it may ave something to do with how i expressed it in the if statement but no matter what i try, i just can't seem to get it to work.

```
namespace NewNew
{
    class Program
    {
        private static double Ans;
        private static double num1;
        private static double num2;
        private static string op;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter First Number: ");
            double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            string op = Console.ReadLine();

            if (op == "+" || op == "-" || op == "/" || op == "*")
                {
                    Calc;
                }
            else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator");
                }

            Console.WriteLine(Ans);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static double Calc(double Ans)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Second Number: ");
            double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            if (op == "+")
            {
                Ans = num1 + num2;
            }
            else if (op == "-")
            {
                Ans = num1 - num2;
            }
            else if (op == "/")
            {
                Ans = num1 / num2;
            }
            else if (op == "*")
            {
                Ans = num1 * num2;
            }
            return Ans;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your program compile? Is there an error? If so what's the error? Which line indicates an error?

Comment: Does that compile?  `op` is declared in Main yet Calc references it, `Calc` is missing the parameter.  And it doesnt seem like the title has anything to do with the problem(s)

Comment: I have the red line underneath "Calc" in the if statement but like i said i can't seem to figure out how i'm supposed to use it. And the title is exactly my problem, that is I can't seem to figure out how to use the method in the if statement. Sorry if this seem like a stupid question. I literally just started trying to learn programming today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I see where you were going but seems like you got off track.

You declared all of these as global:

```
        private static double Ans;
        private static double num1;
        private static double num2;
        private static string op;
```

Each time you re-declared new variables for each with the same name.  You never used those existing, static variables.

```
double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
string op = Console.ReadLine();
```

I think this is what you were after:

```
namespace NewNew
{
    class Program
    {
        private static double Ans;
        private static double num1;
        private static double num2;
        private static string op;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter First Number: ");
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            op = Console.ReadLine();

            if (op == "+" || op == "-" || op == "/" || op == "*")
            {
                Calc();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator");
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Ans);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static double Calc()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Second Number: ");
            num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            if (op == "+")
            {
                Ans = num1 + num2;
            }
            else if (op == "-")
            {
                Ans = num1 - num2;
            }
            else if (op == "/")
            {
                Ans = num1 / num2;
            }
            else if (op == "*")
            {
                Ans = num1 * num2;
            }
            return Ans;
        }
    }
}
```

Though, I would recommend using local variables vs using them globally across the entire class.

Comment: I get an error "No overload for Method "Calc" takes 2 arguements"

Comment: Just edited it.  I think this is what you were really trying to do.

Comment: Ohhhhh, that did the trick, i didn't realize that adding the "double" and "string before the variable would essentially redeclare them completely. So then what happens to the redeclared variables? is there no way to retrieve them? curious. Also, if i try to use them locally, i can't seem to get num1 and op into the method.

Comment: Yup, putting the variable type before the name will declare an entirely new variable.  You can re-use the same variable name if declared in a more globally accessible sense by doing what I did in the answer.

Comment: Personally, what I would do is declare double num1 and string op in the Main function (no need for private or static).  Then pass those variables to Calc(num1, op).  Ans doesn't need to be declared at the class level.  That can be declared inside Calc itself.  Same with num2.

Comment: Just make sure to setup the Calc function like: double Calc(double num1, string op).

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `num1` to your call to `Calc`:

```
if (op == "+" || op == "-" || op == "/" || op == "*")
    {
        Calc(num1);
    }
```

Additionally, you should name the parameter in `Calc` to `num1` instead of `Ans`, so you can reference its value in the `Calc` method:

```
static double Calc(double num1) 
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Compiles but doesn't achieve the desired result, only puts out 0

Answer (score 0):

Method calls require parenthesises after its name e.g `MethodName()`. In this case you also need to pass a double e.g `Calc(2.2)` because you specify that in the method definition

Comment: Hmm, I wanted to be able to input the variables. thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Change your method as below

```
  static void Calc()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Second Number: ");
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        if (op == "+")
        {
            Ans = num1 + num2;
        }
        else if (op == "-")
        {
            Ans = num1 - num2;
        }
        else if (op == "/")
        {
            Ans = num1 / num2;
        }
        else if (op == "*")
        {
            Ans = num1 * num2;
        }

    }
```

in your main method add parenthesis in your function call and remove the re declaration of variables

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter First Number: ");
        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        op = Console.ReadLine();

        if (op == "+" || op == "-" || op == "/" || op == "*")
        {
            Calc();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Ans);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: that got the program to run but unfortunately i only get 0 so i'm guessing none of the variables go through?

Comment: nope, it's because you redefined the variable again. so it uses the new variable not static variables you already defined. that's why you got the 0. however you got the answer, i'll edit my answer though.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I correct your naming convention for best practices always camel case for local variable name and name your variable properly so it will easy for you to read. you may learn on this link for naming convention https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md

Second make sure you use your declared variables, because in your code you didn't use these variable:
`private static double Ans;
        private static double num1;
        private static double num2;
        private static string op;`

and you declare another so that's why you got confuse.

I rewrite your code to more readable code so it will easy to you to understand. But this was a good start keep on writing a code. Be a happy coder :)

```
    private static double answer;
    private static double firstNumber;
    private static double secondNumber;
    private static string operation;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter First Number: ");
        firstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        operation = Console.ReadLine();

        if (operation == "+" || operation == "-" || operation == "/" || operation == "*")
        {
            Calc();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(answer);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static double Calc()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Second Number: ");
         secondNumber = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        if (operation == "+")
        {
            answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        }
        else if (operation == "-")
        {
            answer = firstNumber - secondNumber;
        }
        else if (operation == "/")
        {
            answer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
        }
        else if (operation == "*")
        {
            answer = firstNumber * secondNumber;
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback, i will keep your advice in mind

Comment: @Osmundd'Auvergne I hope you able to compile your code now, just bump me out if you some questions. good work!